# Thread is not terminating

Tags: python, multithreading

Can somebody tell why thread is not terminating here..

```
import sys, threading, select

class MyMaster(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, event_stop):
        super(MyMaster, self).__init__(name='MyMaster')
        self.event_stop = event_stop


    def run(self):
        #waiting for user keyboard Interrupt        
        while not (self.event_stop.isSet():                      
            #Avoiding wait forever condition
            if sys.stdin in  select.select([sys.stdin],[], [],0):
                    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
                    #print "you have entered : ", repr(ch)                
                    if ch == 'a':  
                        #do stuff

                    elif ch == 'h':
                        #do stuff
                    elif ch == 'p':
                        #do stuff
                    elif ch == 'r':
                        #do stuff          
            else:
                print "breaking..........................................."
                break

        print "done"   


    def stop(self):                
        self.event_stop.set()


try:

    event_stop = threading.Event()
    # Creating Master
    master = MyMaster(event_stop)  
    master.start()                                      
    event_stop.wait()
    master.stop()
    print threading.enumerate()
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `event_stop.wait()` in the main thread, which will block until some other thread comes along and calls `event_stop.set()`. However, there is no other thread doing that - the main thread is eventually supposed to do it by calling `master.stop()`, but not until the next line, which can never be reached. You can fix it by simply removing the `event_stop.wait()` call:

```
event_stop = threading.Event()
# Creating Master
master = MyMaster(event_stop)
master.start()
time.sleep(2) # Use this to delay a bit, if that's what you were going for
master.stop()
print threading.enumerate()
```

Comment: Yes there is some other thread which set this. Its like that     event_stop = threading.Event()
    # Creating Master
    master = MyMaster(event_stop)  
    master.start()   
    client = Myclient(event_stop)  
    client.start()     # event_stop is set by this                               
    event_stop.wait()
    master.stop()
    print threading.enumerate()

Comment: @user2764578 Can you edit your question to include all that code? It's impossible to answer the question accurately without it.